# CSV processor spring boot from compute engine

Tags: java, spring-boot

I was working on uploading questions into the server with subject id, chapter_id, grade_id with csv file. so I started with this controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UploadingController
{

    @Autowired
    private UploadingService uploadingService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/uploadBulkMcq/{answer_type}/{subject_id}/{chapter_id}/{grade_id}")
    public ReturnFormat uploadBulkMcq(@PathVariable long answer_type
            , @PathVariable long subject_id
            , @PathVariable long chapter_id
            , @PathVariable long grade_id
            , @RequestParam("files")  MultipartFile file )
    {
        return uploadingService.uploadBulkMCQ( answer_type, subject_id, chapter_id, grade_id, file );
    }

}
```

so in order to create the service class what approach should I follow to upload questions into question table? please help me I really need this help.

Comment: There's a *lot* of approaches which can be undertaken.  We don't even know if you have JPA underneath all of this or not, but it would be better for you to come back after you've made some headway with this problem.  Not knowing where to start doesn't mean it's an acceptable or reasonable question here; if anything, the question you're posing is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all i must say i did something same recently :D 
so here you have to go with multipart because spring boot only supports for multipart.

```
@Service
public class UploadingService
{

    @Autowired
    private QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    public ReturnFormat uploadBulkMCQ(long answer_type, long subject_id, long chapter_id, long grade_id, MultipartFile multipartFile)
    {
        ReturnFormat rf = new ReturnFormat();
        SuccessErrorList selist = new SuccessErrorList();
        try
        {
            File file = convertMultiPartToFile( multipartFile );

            try (Reader reader = new FileReader( file ))
            {
                CsvToBean<McqUploadingFormat> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<McqUploadingFormat>( reader )
                        .withType( McqUploadingFormat.class )
                        .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace( true )
                        .build();

                List<McqUploadingFormat> _questionList = csvToBean.parse();
                List<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<>();

                List<McqUploadingFormat> successList = new ArrayList<>();
                List<McqUploadingFormat> errorList = new ArrayList<>();

                for ( McqUploadingFormat _question : _questionList )
                {
                    Question question = new Question();
                    question.setChapterId( chapter_id );
                    question.setAnswerTypeId( answer_type );
                    question.setSubjectId( subject_id );
                    question.setCreatedBy( _question.getCreated_by() );
                    question.setDifficultyLevel( Integer.parseInt( _question.getDifficulty_level() ) );
                    question.setMultipleAnswers( _question.getMultiple_answers().equals( "1" ) );
                    question.setQuestion( _question.getQuestion() );

                    List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();

                    int i;

                    for ( String a1 : Arrays.asList( _question.getAnswers().split( ";" ) ) )
                    {
                        Answer _answer = new Answer();
                        _answer.setAnswerQuestion( question );
                        i = 0;
                        for ( String a2 : Arrays.asList( a1.split( ":" ) ) )
                        {
                            if ( i == 0 )
                            {
                                _answer.setAnswer( a2 );
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                _answer.setCorrect( a2.equalsIgnoreCase( "Yes" ) || a2.equalsIgnoreCase( "1" ) );
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                        answers.add( _answer );
                    }
                    question.setAnswers( answers );
                    questionList.add( question );
                    successList.add( _question );

                    //add validations for error list
                }

                try
                {
                    questionRepository.save( questionList );
                }
                catch ( Exception e )
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                selist.setSuccessList( successList );
                selist.setErrorList( errorList );

                rf.setStatus( ReturnFormat.Status.SUCCESS );
                rf.setMessage( "Successfully inserted" );
                rf.setData( selist );

            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            rf.setStatus( ReturnFormat.Status.ERROR );
            rf.setMessage( "Exception Occured" );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rf;
    }

    private File convertMultiPartToFile( MultipartFile file ) throws IOException
    {
        File convFile = new File( file.getOriginalFilename() );
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( convFile );
        fos.write( file.getBytes() );
        fos.close();
        return convFile;
    }

    private void saveQuestion( Question question )
    {
        for ( Answer answer : question.getAnswers() )
        {
            answer.setAnswerQuestion( question );
        }
        questionRepository.save( question );
    }

}
```

this is the service class i have edited for you. and

```
public class ReturnFormat
{
    private Status status;
    private String message;
    private Object data;

    public ReturnFormat()
    {
    }

    public ReturnFormat( Status status, String message, Object data )
    {
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Status getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus( Status status )
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage( String message )
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Object getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData( Object data )
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public enum Status
    {
        SUCCESS, ERROR, CREATED, UPDATED, DELETED, FOUND, NOT_FOUND
    }

}
```